# LINQ XML C# remove where condition in loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Trying to delete nodes under certain conditions. Basically if certain checkboxes are checked I give an extra query with WHERE statement to my IENumerable named upit. After the queries has been set im trying to delete them iterating through every one, but nothing gets deleted everytime.

```
XDocument X = XDocument.Load(@"Financije.xml");
var upit = X.Element("POPIS").Elements("PODACI");

if (mjesec.Checked) { upit = upit.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("MJESEC").Value) == Convert.ToInt32(mjesecbox.Text))); }
if (godina.Checked) { upit = upit.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("GODINA").Value) == Convert.ToInt32(godinabox.Text))); }
if (ime.Checked) { upit = upit.Where(E => (E.Element("IME").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToString().ToLower()))); }
if (opis.Checked) { upit = upit.Where(E => (E.Element("OPIS").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToString().ToLower()))); }
if (veceod.Checked) { upit = upit.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("CIJENA").Value.ToString()) > Convert.ToInt32(iznos.Text.ToString()))); }
if (manjeod.Checked) { upit = upit.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("CIJENA").Value.ToString()) < Convert.ToInt32(iznos.Text.ToString()))); }

foreach (var item in upit)
{
    upit.Remove();
}
```

and this is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<POPIS>
  <PODACI>
    <IME>test</IME>
    <CIJENA>200</CIJENA>
    <DATUM>12.1.2019</DATUM>
    <MJESEC>1</MJESEC>
    <GODINA>2019</GODINA>
    <OPIS>test123333</OPIS>
  </PODACI>
  <PODACI>
    <IME>voda</IME>
    <CIJENA>230</CIJENA>
    <DATUM>12.4.2018</DATUM>
    <MJESEC>4</MJESEC>
    <GODINA>2018</GODINA>
    <OPIS>yes123no</OPIS>
  </PODACI>
  <PODACI>
    <IME>oops</IME>
    <OPIS>nice</OPIS>
    <CIJENA>3</CIJENA>
    <MJESEC>5</MJESEC>
    <GODINA>2018<GODINA/>
    <DATUM>24.02.2019</DATUM>
  </PODACI>
  <PODACI>
    <IME>test</IME>
    <OPIS>123</OPIS>
    <CIJENA>1</CIJENA>
    <MJESEC>12</MJESEC>
    <GODINA>2019<GODINA/>
    <DATUM>24.02.2019</DATUM>
  </PODACI>
</POPIS>
```

Comment: At first, if you want to keep the original IEnumerable, you should define a second one, but it seems you only want one. Next, if you want to remove an item you should use `upit.Remove(item);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you want to end up with, but I assume you want to exclude items where they fail at least one case where the checkbox is checked and that comparison you are doing fails. 
So below achieves it in one query:

```
var X = XDocument.Load("Financije.xml");
var upit = X.Element("POPIS").Elements("PODACI");

var toRemove = upit.Where(u => 
    // If mjesec is not checked, skip the predicate, otherwise evaluate it.
    (!mjesec.Checked     || (Convert.ToInt32(u.Element("MJESEC").Value) == Convert.ToInt32(mjesecbox.Text)))
    // *And* do the same for godina and the rest of checkboxes...
    && (!godina.Checked  || (Convert.ToInt32(u.Element("GODINA").Value) == Convert.ToInt32(godinabox.Text)))
    && (!ime.Checked     || (u.Element("IME").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToString().ToLower())))
    && (!opis.Checked    || (u.Element("OPIS").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToString().ToLower())))
    && (!veceod.Checked  || (Convert.ToInt32(u.Element("CIJENA").Value.ToString()) > Convert.ToInt32(iznos.Text.ToString())))
    && (!manjeod.Checked || (Convert.ToInt32(u.Element("CIJENA").Value.ToString()) < Convert.ToInt32(iznos.Text.ToString()))));  

X.Element("POPIS").ReplaceAll(upit.Except(toRemove));
X.Save("Financije.xml");
```

Comment: Although this isn't what I needed, I appreciate your help. My initial plan was to have a query (which changes depending on checkboxes selected) and loop through every one of them, deleting them from the XML file forever.

Comment: @Wuzbee hm, maybe you could then try replacing the content of what `upit` is - with something like `X.Element("POPIS").ReplaceWith(upit)`?

Comment: Ignore everything. I will just start going from basics building up the queries, for now let's make the basic example work. I found this [example](https://imgur.com/ChrLVEK) and Im trying  and im trying to make it work. Following the code I came up with this.   
 `XDocument X = XDocument.Load(@"Financije.xml");     
 X.Element("POPIS").Elements("PODACI").Where(s => s.Elements("IME").Any(l => l.Value == textBox1.ToString())).Remove();`  
  I dont see why this code wouldn't work, but suprisingly it doesn't.

Comment: Well are you sure `l => l.Value == textBox1.ToString()` evaluates to what you want? What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: @Wuzbee okay, I think I got it working with `.ReplaceAll()` and `.Save()`. I think it should achieve what you want - please see the edit.

Comment: It does the exact opposite. The one I want to remove is the only one that gets left while all others get removed. Im trying to invert it by using "!" but no luck. Its almost working though, thanks so much man.

Comment: Lets say I have an ID value 1. Typing 1 in textbox and pressing the button I would want to have only the one with ID value 1 deleted - instead of ID i have node named name, opis...

Comment: Hm, maybe we can use `.Except()` then? See the edit.

Comment: I was going through available functions and missed that one. Thank you so much! Everything works well now.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
XDocument X = XDocument.Load(@"Financije.xml");
    var upit = X.Element("POPIS").Elements("PODACI");
    //I‘m only on phone so please excuse, if I take the wrong Type. Assign to null, to prevent Compiler-Error 
    IEnumerable<XElement> upitPart= null;
    if (mjesec.Checked) { upitPart = upit.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("MJESEC").Value) == Convert.ToInt32(mjesecbox.Text))); }
    if (godina.Checked) { upitPart = upitPart.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("GODINA").Value) == Convert.ToInt32(godinabox.Text))); }
    if (ime.Checked) { upitPart = upitPart.Where(E => (E.Element("IME").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToString().ToLower()))); }
    if (opis.Checked) { upitPart = upitPart.Where(E => (E.Element("OPIS").Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.Text.ToString().ToLower()))); }
    if (veceod.Checked) { upitPart = upitPart.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("CIJENA").Value.ToString()) > Convert.ToInt32(iznos.Text.ToString()))); }
    if (manjeod.Checked) { upitPart = upitPart.Where(E => (Convert.ToInt32(E.Element("CIJENA").Value.ToString()) < Convert.ToInt32(iznos.Text.ToString()))); }

if(upitPart != null)
{
    foreach (var item in upitPart)
    {
        upit.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Throws 2 errors. "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IEnumerable<XElement>" at your 4th line and "No overload for method 'Remove' takes 1 arguments" at upit.Remove(item);

Comment: made some changes try it.

Comment: Still the same problem, take a look. [link](https://imgur.com/a/rhV7o90)

Comment: Uhm, why did you basically steal @Nikolaus answer?